# How to get a list of student below Avg() 60% in Hibernate Criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I am trying to get a list of student whose average is less than 60%. I tried to so this in the following way,

```
public List<Object> getMonthwiseAvgStudentBelowCriteria() throws Exception { //int forMonth, String batch
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        List<Object> answers = null;
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        answers = new ArrayList<Object>();

        DetachedCriteria leapAnsr = null;
            answers = new ArrayList<Object>();
            leapAnsr = DetachedCriteria
                    .forClass(LeapAnswers.class, "questions");

            ProjectionList list = Projections.projectionList();
            list.add(Projections.avg("quesAns.subQuestionAnswer").as("avg"));
            //list.add(Property.forName("quesAns.subQuestionAnswer").avg());
            list.add(Projections.groupProperty("questions.studentId"));
            list.add(Projections.property("questions.batch"));

            leapAnsr.add(Restrictions.eq("questions.month", 6 + ""));//forMonth
            leapAnsr.add(Restrictions.eq("questions.year", "2013-14"));//leap.getYear()
            leapAnsr.add(Restrictions.eq("questions.from", 6));//leap.getFrom()
            leapAnsr.add(Restrictions.eq("questions.to", 3));//leap.getTo()
            leapAnsr.add(Restrictions.lt("avg", 6.0));

            //leapAnsr.add(Property.forName("quesAns.subQuestionAnswer").avg().lt("6"));

            leapAnsr.add(Restrictions.eq("questions.batch", "k"));

            leapAnsr.setFetchMode("questions.questionAnswerSets",
                    FetchMode.JOIN);
            leapAnsr.createAlias("questions.questionAnswerSets", "ques",
                    CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN);

            leapAnsr.createAlias("ques.subQuestionAnswers", "quesAns",
                    CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN);
            leapAnsr.add(Restrictions.ne("quesAns.subQuestionAnswer", "N"));
            leapAnsr.setProjection(list);


            answers = leapAnsr.getExecutableCriteria(session).list();
            session.flush();
            session.clear();

        return answers;
    }
```

please tell me how to write hibernate criteria for this.
I am getting following error,

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'y0_' in 'where clause'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1053)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4096)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4028)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2490)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2651)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2734)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2322)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1812)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:697)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2232)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2129)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2124)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1597)
    at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:306)
    at in.coep.vlabteam.leap.DAOServiceImpl.LeapAnswersDAOImpl.getMonthwiseAvgStudentBelowCriteria(LeapAnswersDAOImpl.java:846)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy39.getMonthwiseAvgStudentBelowCriteria(Unknown Source)
    at in.coep.vlabteam.leap.controllers.LeapProgramController.sendNotificationMail(LeapProgramController.java:499)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:212)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:900)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:146)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:928)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:539)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:300)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
14:34:14,591 DEBUG SqlUtils:85 - Attempted to convert SQLException to SQLException. Leaving it alone. [SQLState: 42S22; errorCode: 1054]
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'y0_' in 'where clause'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1053)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4096)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4028)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2490)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2651)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2734)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2322)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1812)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:697)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2232)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2129)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2124)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1597)
    at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:306)
    at in.coep.vlabteam.leap.DAOServiceImpl.LeapAnswersDAOImpl.getMonthwiseAvgStudentBelowCriteria(LeapAnswersDAOImpl.java:846)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy39.getMonthwiseAvgStudentBelowCriteria(Unknown Source)
    at in.coep.vlabteam.leap.controllers.LeapProgramController.sendNotificationMail(LeapProgramController.java:499)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:212)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:900)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:146)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:928)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:539)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:300)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I want a list of student whose avg is below 60%.

Comment: So whats wrong in the way you tried? Getting an exception? Not getting the desired output? What is the expected output? And what are you getting instead?

Comment: I want to a list of student below 60%

Answer (score 0):

First create Criteria as follows

```
Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(YourClassName.class);
```

Then you can take that Students list as follows

```
     // Add restriction.
     cr.add(Restrictions.lt("avg", 60));
     List studentList= cr.list();
```

Comment: but in above code what is that "avg" in Restrictions.lt("avg", 60)??

Comment: In your Student bean you can define that avg field

Comment: @HarshalChaudhari refer this http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-criteria-examples/ for more details

Comment: Thanks Ruchi. But is there another solution for this.

Comment: @HarshalChaudhari here is a good guide about hibernate criteria http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Java/Hibernate-Criteria-Queries-in-Depth/2/
I think this will be a good way to archive your requirement.